# Opening and controlling a window over ssh

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, remote-x-session

I have a raspberry pi to which a monitor is connected. I have ssh'd into this raspberry pi from another box. What I want to do now is:

- Open a window (ie a browser) **on the monitor connected to the raspberry pi**
- Be able to interact with this window using the mouse and keyboard connected to the box I am using

All via the box from which I've ssh'd into the raspberry pi. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how on-topic we are here given this is more about the non-Ubuntu Raspi than the local Ubuntu computer... But given that this also applies to a pure Ubuntu→Ubuntu set up and in the interest of being useful, I'll plod on...

1. You just need to point to the right DISPLAY when you run graphical things over SSH so in your case:

   ```
   DISPLAY=:0 firefox
   ```
2. To then control the application is then a little harder. [I found out about x2x a couple of weeks ago](https://askubuntu.com/q/358934/449) and it seems to do the job. You'll need to install `x2x` on the raspi and run a separate SSH session out to it like so:

   ```
   ssh -X raspi x2x -to :0
   ```

Comment: Running "DISPLAY=:1 chromium-browser" got me the wanted window on the correct monitor. Step 2 is not working for me though. Running "ssh -X pi x2x -to :1" results in a new window appearing in the taskbar of my KDE, though nothing seems to be attached to it. If I right click it and pick "maximize", I get a window with just ":1" in it, which is also the title of the Window. Any idea what could be wrong?